# Links removed from google search results

Tags: seo, google, google-search, googlebot

For my website www.trickwarehouse.com i have created one post on keyloggers. When i search in google that `what are keyloggers?` then my website's post position was 16 but after 1 hour, when i checked once again then **BOOOM!!!!** nothing found for my website within top 100 results. and also other keywords which was in top 100 results was shifted behind by 2-3 results......
 Why it is happening?
Any answers?

Comment: We can't really answer this for you, we aren't Google. Have you tried logging into Google Webmasters? What does it say about your site? Does it say pages were removed?

Comment: No nothing is different in webmasters..... Just removed

Comment: SERPs are known to change, this isn't unusual. It is also possible the results haven't updated across all of Google's search datacenters.

Comment: Sorry but the question is too specific and would unlikely help other visitors. Furthermore, there are dozens of questions and answers regarding drop of rankings, how to increase rankings and so on already on Pro Webmasters. Feel free to ask this question in our [Chat Channel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters)